# HttpURLConnection getResponseCode() not working

Tags: java, android, url

I have a problem with `getResponseCode()`, it doesn´t work:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.io.IOException;
```

Function:

```
public static int checkURL(String u) throws IOException {
    java.net.URL url = new URL(u);
    System.out.println("LLEGA :::::::::: " + url);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    int code = connection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH "+code);
    return code;
}
```

LogCat:

```
System.out:LLEGA:::::::::: http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/webservice_balanza/deboinventario/webservice.php
System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-1-249171107: SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-1-249171107: SMARTBONDING_FEATURE_ENABLED is true
System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
```

Please help me !

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, "don't work"?

Comment: i can't get the response code... 
It worked before and now not...

Comment: Add breakpoints when your connection opens and getResponseCode is called. See if your code variable has any value afterwards. URL may be a problem as well.

Comment: Firewall or network issue maybe? Did you tried on different times?

Comment: its a network issue...

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like the code is correct. t least this works as expected:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      int code = connection.getResponseCode();
      System.out.println(code);
   }

}
```

Are you sure your URL is valid? If so, have you tried debugging?